# ¿Como hacer una funcion "swap" con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

espero que estén bien. La cosa es que estoy empezando a aprender JavaScript y me gustaría hacer una función Swap, que intercambie los valores dentro de una funcion que se encarga de realizar un quicksort a un array, la cosa es que cuando ejecuto la funcion de swap, no me intercambia los valores, me podria ayudar?, aqui esta el codigo:

```
var arr = [];

function insertarElementos(arr, val){
    arr.push(val);
}

function swap(a, b){
    let aux = a;
    a = b;
    b = aux;
}

function quickSort(arr, izq, der){
    if(izq>=der){
        return;
    }
    let piv = arr[izq];
    let m = izq;
    let n = der;
    while(true){
        do{
            m++;
        }while(arr[m] <= piv && m<der);
        do{
            n--;
        }while(arr[n] >= piv && n>izq);
        if(m>=n){
            break;
        }
        /*let aux = arr[izq];
        arr[izq] = arr[n];
        arr[n] = aux;*/
        swap(arr[izq], arr[n]);
    }
    /*let aux = arr[izq];
    arr[izq] = arr[n];
    arr[n] = aux;*/
    swap(arr[izq], arr[n]);
    quickSort(arr, izq, n-1);
    quickSort(arr, n+1, der);
}
```

Comment: No pases los valores del `Array` a tu función, en cambio pasa los índices y usalos dentro de tu función para hacer el *swap* a los elementos del `Array` según el índice que estás pasando. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Si me ayudo muchas gracias, Saludos, que pases un buen dia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/381219/como-hacer-una-funcion-swap-con-javascript#comment682896_381219) te planteo que pases los índices en vez de los valores, esto es porque cuando haces esto:

```
swap(arr[izq], arr[n])
```

estás pasando el valor de la posición `izq` y `n` y se los estás asignando a las variables `a` y `b` respectivamente (locales a tu función). Luego dichas variables sólo existen dentro de tu función.

Lo que deberías hacer es lo siguiente:

```
swap(izq, n)
```

Y la firma de tu función debe ser:

```
function swap(a, b) {
  let aux = arr[a];
  arr[a] = arr[b];
  arr[b] = aux;
}
```

Con esto si que estás alterando los valores del `array`.